# Basic ODE with Initial Value

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

old guy here working through an old ODE book (separable equations):

$(\ln y^x)dy = 3x^2ydx$ which rearranges to:

$ln (y)/y dy = 3x dx$

solving this yields:

$(ln y)^2 = (3x^2)/2 + C$

initial boundary: $y(2) = e^3$

My answer: $(ln y)^2 = 3x^2/2 +3$

Book's answer: $(ln y)^2 = 3x^2 + 3$ <- I also copied this wrong, should be (- 3), but I forgot to bring the 1/2 when I did the integration.

I don't see how they just removed the 2 from $3x^2/2$.  Did I forget everything in 20 years about just lumping that value in with the integration constant C?

Comment: Ugh, hit enter by accident while still typing...

Comment: It seems you are missing a half in your integration of $\log(y)/y$

Comment: @OliverDiaz yep.  20 years induces silly mistakes.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I copied down the book answer incorrectly also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in your integral on the LHS:

$\int\frac{ln(y)}{y}dy = \frac{1}{2}{ln(y)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln (y)/y dy = 3x dx$$
$$\ln (y) d\ln y = 3x dx$$
Integration gives us:
$$\ln^2 y=3x^2+C$$

Initial condition gives $C=9-12=-3$
$$\implies \ln^2 y=3x^2-3$$